# execute all eclipse suggestions marker

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

I downloaded an Android Open Source Project, but Once I imported it in Eclipse, a lot of project errors appeared.
I figured out that all this errors are caused by some wrong "@Override" declarations.
Now, I noticed that, for each file, Eclipse suggests me in the markers Column to remove that Wrong declaration.
So, is there a way to tell eclipse to "auto-execute" all of his suggestions in a determinate project?

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

I dont have straight answer for your question, but one possible work around is set compilance level to 1.6 will resolve this issue. Window--> Preferences-->Java --->Compiler--?compilance level--> change to 1.6 or higher.